# OpenLiteSpeed file_put_contents Permission Denied Error

Tags: php, file-permissions, litespeed

New to OpenLiteSpeed, I received a permission denied warning error when trying to write a file in the website subdirectory using file_put_contents() API from PHP. I thought perhaps I needed to adjust the open_basedir in **/usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/etc/php/7.3/litespeed/php.ini** and restarted OpenLiteSpeed, but the warning persisted. I then did `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` where I had the websites in my configuration, but that didn't seem to help. I then played with chown to open up permissions for the directory of the file I wanted to edit, and then the file itself. Nothing seems to work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the proper folder permission with OpenLiteSpeed for where you place the files should be **nobody:nogroup**, not **www-data:www-data** like it would be with Apache. So, since I was placing all my web files under some path in /var/www, I did `chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/www` and the problem went away.